# Socket P - How to search on Intel ARK

Tags: cpu

.Hi! I went looking for new CPU to an old laptop, replacing an Intel Pentium T3200, but I can't filter them by Socket P on Intel's ARK.

1. How to search for cpus with Socket P on Intel's ARK website?
2. Can I put an Intel PGA478 CPU into the Socket P?

Comment: They are not compatible with one another.  Your question about how to find information on the Intel website is out of scope.

Comment: You're going to first want to determine what CPUs are actually compatible with your laptop's model, either via the OEM's site or via a forum, as you can't just buy a CPU that fits the socket - laptops don't support that; OEMs often lock the BIOS/UEFI firmware to either one specific processor or a specific handful. Installing a CPU the board does not support, regardless if it's the right socket size or not, will result in a refusal to POST and display a CPU related error code.

Comment: Sorry to say I never have been able to search on ARK for CPU characteristics as you wish to do, and I use ARK at least once an hour during the workday to look up this or that.

Comment: @K7AAY it is Intel Pentium T3200 it uses now

Comment: @TBQP the laptop make and model is also required, please update your question with this, and the above information _(i.e. please don't post it in a comment)_.